# Non Users Delete Posts

Tags: wordpress, posts

How can I allow non users to delete posts?

I am currently using this code:

```
<?php
  global $wp_query;
  $cat = get_the_category();

  if ($cat[0]->cat_ID == 86){
      $url = get_bloginfo('url');
      echo "<a>ID) . "'>Delete post</a>";
 }
?>
```

This adds a delete link if the current post is in a certain category. It works perfectly but It requires a user with edit privileges to be logged in. How can I change this to allow for regular, non registered users to delete posts?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Promote non-users into users by giving them a session to uniquely identify them and relate each poster with their posts.  This requires additional session storage for non-users.

2) Generate a unique hash for each post and provide in the view page a once-only option to delete the post.  Similarly to imgur.com, they can still delete the post if they saved the link but will not be presented again.  This saves server state.